# Height varies forma

Tags: css

How can I set the height of forma grow while entering new things?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: nobody will understand this until correct the spelling and add more than a dozen words.

Comment: I have a form that is supposed to grow all the time came to dynamic data, and bake color is black and I can not grow what do we do?

Comment: You best show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that I'm translating correctly:

> How can I set the height of a form, so that it will grow when more content is added?

You either don't need to (a form, and other block-level elements, will grow to accommodate its contents), or, if the problem is that you've already specified a `height` that's causing newly-added elements to be hidden, you can set:

```
form {
    min-height: 200px; /* or whatever to set *minimum* height */
    overflow: auto; /* to show scroll-bars if the
                       content is longer than the container, or
    overflow: hidden;  if the form's content is `float`-ed */
}
```

Otherwise, if you could edit your question for clarity, I'll try and address the actual problem. Whatever that might be.

1. [JS Fiddle demo, featuring **no defined** `height`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sxaMU/3/).
2. [JS Fiddle demo, featuring defined `height` and `overflow: auto`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sxaMU/).
3. [JS Fiddle demo, featuring floated `fieldset` elements, and `overflow: hidden` on the form](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sxaMU/1/).

(**Note:** *all* demonstrations feature dynamically-added content (click the `+` character to the right of each `input`)).